# How to make mail() message spacing

Tags: php, html, email

I found an issue with spacing in mail() function. This is my code:

```
$headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$mailmsg = "Odpověď na nábor:" .$name.".\n\n\n\nDiscord:".$discord.".\n\nVěk:".$vek . '?=';
```

The \n does nothing and the mail looks like this

> Odpověď na nábor:Kolomboootest.Discord:Kolombooo#3257. Věk:15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `\n` is meaningless in HTML and you've set the email's content type to HTML.

In HTML you can use `<br/>` to make new lines.